# Object that stores two vars with the same name

Tags: java

In this code I allocate one only object, but in some way I store 2 copies of x (one for the base class and one for the subclass). How is it possible if the object is only one? Where is the space found to store two x vars? Does it mean in reality two objects are createed?

```
class App {

    class Base {
        public int x;

        public Base() {
            x = 2;
        }

        int method() {
            return x;
        }
    }

    class Subclass extends Base {
        public int x;

        public Subclass() {
            x = 3;
        }

        int method() {
            return x;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        Base b = new Subclass();
        System.out.println(b.x);
        System.out.println(b.method());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One `x` belongs to the superclass and the other to the subclass. The fact that they have the same name is of no importance and you can access both by qualifying your access expression with the class:

```
((Base)b).x
((Subclass)b).x
```

(note that the cast in the first line is not necessary; I've put it in for symmetry)

Answer (score 0):

In java you can not overload `variables`.,Though they are with the same name,their classes are different.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [`tutorial`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)(in section "What You Can Do in a Subclass"), when you declare a field in the subclass with the same name as the one in the superclass, in this case `x`, the one in the superclass will be hidden, which means that there're actually two `x`s in the subclass, one for itself, the other for its superclass, only baring the same name `x`. You can reference to the one in the derived class using `derivedObject.x` and the one in the subclass using `((Base)derivedObject).x`(or super.x if within the derived class)